# expected promary-expression before "void" c++

Tags: c++, adventure

Hey I'm new to c++ I don't see any problem with my code.
I was trying to make a very basic make your own adventure game.
Thanks for your time.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void next();

int main()
{

    int x;
    int y;
    int z;

    cout << "Welcome To \n";
    cout << "killing the Dragon! \n";
    cout << endl;

    cout << "There Is a Road infront of you you may go left or right \n";
    cout << "Left = any other number, Right = 1 \n";
    cin >> x;
    if(x == 1){
         do{       
            cout << "A rock blocks your bath \n";
            cout << "You Go back \n"; // Fix loop problem "Can't choose 0 more the  once of it all screws up"
            cout << "Left = 0, Right = 1 \n";
            cin >> x;
            if(x == 0){next();}
           }while(x == 1);

                  void next(){
                  cout << "You Come up to a small village \n";
                  cout << "You find 100 gold coins in your pocket \n";
                  cout << "You may continue your bath or buy a sword at the local blacksmith \n";
                  cout << "Continue = 1, buy sword = any other number \n";
                  cin >> y;  

    if(y == 1){                
    cout << "You buy the sword for 50G's and continue with your adventure \n";
    cout << "You find a dragon down the road luckaly you have your sword! \n";
    cout << "Do you kill the Dragon or let him live? \n";
    cout << "murder the but cack = 1, Let him live = any other Number \n";
    cin >> z;                 
              }else{          
              cout << "You continue your bath and get pwnd by a dragon down the road your a failure \n";
              system("pause");
              return 0;       
                   }          

    if(z == 1){               
    cout << "YA YOU PWNED THE DRAGON GRATZ BRO YOU NOW HAVE THE TITLE DRAGON SLAYER AND YOU MADE 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000G'S \n";
    system("pause");          
    return 0;                 
              }else{          
              cout << "you got owned by the dragon! ITS a DRAGON what where you thinking letting it \nlive now your dead hope your happy! \n";
              system("pause");
              return 0;       
                   }          
                   }          
                             }

}
```

Also if you could give me some help full coding advice to keep the code more clean and organized, right now all I'm doing is making sure that all the curly brasses are all lined up with one another and every second if statement gets pushed back so that it doesn't make a kind of star affect with the code.

Comment: Functions go outside of other functions.

Comment: And use functions at all... That will get you a really big mess of if statements if you don't learn to use functions. If one gets back to the same room, you'd have to code it again etc. I suggest you use a decent IDE (available for all major OS's for free), then the code formatting will be mostly taken care of.

Answer (score 2):

You've made a function inside another one:

```
int main()
{
   ...

   void next() { ... } // Illegal !

   ...

}
```

It's illegal for regular functions (you can do it by lambda functions also). I think you confused between function and `goto` jumps (which is not good practice to use it). I think you don't need a function in your case. Because the function `next` has many dependencies to the main's local variables. By the way, you can put the inner function, outside of main function.

And, a good indentation can help you to organization and format your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void next();

int main()
{

    int x;
    int y;


    cout << "Welcome To \n";
    cout << "killing the Dragon! \n";
    cout << endl;

    cout << "There Is a Road infront of you you may go left or right \n";
    cout << "Left = any other number, Right = 1 \n";
    cin >> x;
    if(x == 1){
         do{
            cout << "A rock blocks your bath \n";
            cout << "You Go back \n"; // Fix loop problem "Can't choose 0 more the    once of it all screws up"
            cout << "Left = 0, Right = 1 \n";
            cin >> x;
            if(x == 0){
            next();
            }
           }while(x == 1);


                    }

}
void next()
{
    int y;
    int z;

    cout << "You Come up to a small village \n";
    cout << "You find 100 gold coins in your pocket \n";
    cout << "You may continue your bath or buy a sword at the local blacksmith \n";
    cout << "Continue = 1, buy sword = any other number \n";
    cin >> y;

    if(y == 1){
    cout << "You buy the sword for 50G's and continue with your adventure \n";
    cout << "You find a dragon down the road luckaly you have your sword! \n";
    cout << "Do you kill the Dragon or let him live? \n";
    cout << "murder the but cack = 1, Let him live = any other Number \n";
    cin >> z;
    }else{
        cout << "You continue your bath and get pwnd by a dragon down the road your a failure \n";
        system("pause");
                   }
    if(z == 1){
    cout << "YA YOU PWNED THE DRAGON GRATZ BRO YOU NOW HAVE THE TITLE DRAGON SLAYER AND YOU MADE 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000G'S \n";
    system("pause");
              }else{
              cout << "you got owned by the dragon! ITS a DRAGON what where you thinking letting it \nlive now your dead hope your happy! \n";
              system("pause");
                   }
                   }
```

i fixed your code, i found 10 errors and fixed all of them. If you want to use the system calls which is very unadvisable, then you need the cstdlib header file.  Also, the void function was returning a value. that is illegal in c++. A function inside a function is also illegal